# In xamarin iOS - get [indexPath.Row] in UITableViewCell, Using button click event

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

In Xamarin  iOS - I have a class named `TableCell ( public class TableCell : UITableViewCell { } )` - in this class I have declared buttons.

In button click event , i'm trying to access `[indexPath.Row]` in `UITableViewCell`. I can select a row to find `[indexPath.Row]` in `UITableViewSource`.

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource {
//  - - - -
 public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight

  }

// - - - -

}
```

How can I get `[indexPath.Row]` in `UITableViewCell`, Using button click event ..?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best approach but it will definitely work:

I would extend TableCell class with a new property:

```
public NSIndexPath IndexPath { get; set; }
```

Then I would add this line to the UITableViewSource's GetCell method if you are using the cell reusing pattern:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
       TableCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("YourIdentifier") ?? new TableCell();
       cell.IndexPath = indexPath;
       return cell;
    }
```

And after that you could access the cell's current IndexPath anywhere. i.e.:

```
public TableCell()
{
     UIButton btn = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundRect);
     btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, args)
     {
           new UIAlertView("Button pressed!", indexPath.Row, null, "OK", null).Show();
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm still working through the code you supplied and also with some new classes, I appreciate the help. Thanks and ll get back soon.

Comment: If you need any more help feel free to contact me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [VisibleCells](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=P%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UITableView.VisibleCells) property.
As soon as user selected row, the `UITableViewCell` will be visible.

---

Alternative solution (if you want to get similar, but **not the same** cell):
You can get it via `UITableViewCell.GetCell` using passed `UITableView tableView`, then cast it into your type of `UITableViewCell`, then call it's method using passed `NSIndexPath indexPath`.

Something like this:

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource {
    //  - - - -
     public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
        var cell = tableView.GetCell(tableView, indexPath);
        var myCell class = cell as MyCellClass;
        if (myCell != null) {
            // TODO: do something with cell.
        }          
      }
    // - - - -
    }
// - - - -
}
```